# apache hang on deadlock

Tags: mysql, deadlock

i use code like this  to prevent deadlock.

```
while($retry<3 and $notsone)
{
try
{
$transaction->commit();
$notdone=false;
}
catch
{
$transaction->rollback();
$retry++;
}
}
if ($retry==3)
{
throw new exeption("deadlock found!");
}
```

i test code with running code in 6 different browser concurrently . sometimes in some browser i see a deadlock found message but sometimes i got a message from apache http server.
apache http server has stopped working. i have 2 option. close program or check for online solution.

my question is do concurrency problem cause apache hang?
how to prevant this?

Comment: How long are the hangs?  The default lock wait timeout is 50 seconds.  Deadlocks are detected immediately.

Comment: i got a message from apache http server. apache http server has stopped working. i have 2 option. close program or check for online solution.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL has built in [deadlock detection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-deadlock-detection.html) and detects a deadlock as soon as it occurs.  If you need to detect deadlocks, you will have to examine the error message coming back from the failed transaction, or use [pt-deadlock-logger](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.0/pt-deadlock-logger.html) to log deadlocks external to the application.

The code you have supplied doesn't detect deadlocks.  It detects failed transactions and retries 3 times.  If the transaction took a long time, you will occupy an apache worker for three times as long as the transaction took.  If the failure occurs due to a lock timing out (note locks and deadlocks are very different), the code above could take up to 2.5 minutes to return to the browser, assuming you have [innodb_lock_wait_timeout](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_lock_wait_timeout) set to the default of 50 seconds.  That's a long long time.

Can we step back and ask what is it that you are trying to accomplish with this code path?

(side note, I think this belongs on stackoverflow, not here as this seems more like a PHP/development question).

Comment: i decrease innodb_lock_wait_timeout and increase ..._pool_size but sometimes i get a error 2 secound after running code. i have no idea why 2 second!?

Comment: You will need to provide more details about what queries are causing this problem.  The output of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS\G and SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST\G **while the problem is occurring** would be a good place to start.

Comment: i used ENGINE INNODB STATUS but beacause of apache error it doesnt help and i cant see any output.

Comment: You need to look at SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS and SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST from within the mysql command line client, not from apache.